# Delete old files in unix using python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python code below that needs to check for csv files older than 12 days and delete them. But it is not deleting the files. What's wrong with the code?

```
import os, sys, time, glob, datetime
from subprocess import call



file_path = '/export/data/history'
now = time.time()
files = os.listdir(file_path)
os.chdir(file_path)
extension = 'csv'
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
# files = os.path.join(dirs, '')
print(result)
a = 0

def getCurrentTime():
    currentTime=datetime.datetime.now()
    return currentTime

def getTimeDifference(path):
    last_modified_time =datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path))
    #print("modifid time = ")
    print("Last modifid Date = "+str(last_modified_time))
    timeDiff = getCurrentTime() - last_modified_time
    return timeDiff

for xfile in result:
    if os.path.isfile( file_path + xfile ):
                d1 = getTimeDifference(file_path + xfile)
                if(d1.days >= 12):
                        os.remove(xfile)
                        a= a+1

print (str(a)+' csv files deleted .')
```

I am using python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more pythonic way to do it, using a generic function.

```
from os import path, listdir, remove
from datetime import datetime as dt


def remove_old_files(folder, extension, days_delta):
    now = dt.now()
    files_to_by_extension = [path.join(folder, f) for f in listdir(folder) if
                             f.endswith(extension)]
    removed_files_counter = 0
    for f in files_to_by_extension:
        delta = now - dt.fromtimestamp(path.getmtime(f))
        if delta.days > days_delta:
            try:
                remove(f)
                removed_files_counter += 1
            except OSError:
                pass

    return removed_files_counter


num_of_removed_files = remove_old_files('/tmp', 'txt', 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is the way your file paths are created:

`if os.path.isfile( file_path + xfile )`

and

`os.remove(xfile)`

Use `os.path.join` instead:

```
for xfile in result:
    fp = os.path.join(file_path, xfile)
    if os.path.isfile(fp):
        d1 = getTimeDifference(fp)
        if(d1.days >= 12):
            os.remove(fp)
```

Also the below line will return all files in the current working directory, not the path specified with the `file_path` variable

`result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]`

Change to:

`result = [i for i in glob.glob('{}*.{}'.format(file_path, extension))]`

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code to something like this:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

FILE_PATH = '/export/data/history'
EXTENSIONS = ('.csv',)
DAYS = 12


def get_time_difference(path):
    return datetime.now() - datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path))


def remove_old_files(file_path, extensions, n_days):
    deleted_files = {ext: () for ext in extensions}
    day_delta = timedelta(days=n_days)
    for curr_file in filter(lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1] in extensions, next(os.walk(file_path))[2]):
        to_delete = os.path.join(file_path, curr_file)
        if get_time_difference(to_delete) >= day_delta:
            os.remove(to_delete)
            deleted_files[os.path.splitext(curr_file)[1]] += (to_delete,)

    return deleted_files


if __name__ == '__main__':
    deleted_files = remove_old_files(FILE_PATH, EXTENSIONS, DAYS)
    for ext, ext_del_files in deleted_files.items():
        print('{} {} files has been deleted.'.format(len(ext_del_files), ext))
        print('\tDeleted files: {}'.format(' '.join(ext_del_files)))
```

This code depends only from `os` and `datetime` modules.

The [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk) finds all the files in the input path, while the `filter` function skips all the files whose extension is not in the selected ones (`'.csv'` in this example); in this case, [`os.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) is used to extract the extension of each file.

To decide if a file is old enough to be deleted, [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) objects are used.

The function `remove_old_files` returns a `dict` containing for each extension a tuple with the correspondent deleted files.

I hope this could help.